# 1つのドメインに2つのDKIMを設定する方法

Tags: dns

お世話になります。

現在、レンタルサーバーでメールアドレスを運用しているのですが、事情があって、メールの運用は別のメールサーバーで行うことにしました。
ただ、一部のメールアドレスだけどうしてもレンタルサーバーで運用する必要があり、DNSの設定に少し困っています。
SPFレコードは、下記のように指定することで複数のIPアドレスを指定できることは確認しました。

```
v=spf1 +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -all
```

しかし、DKIMはどのように指定すればよいのでしょうか。
どちらのサーバーでもDKIM追加時のセレクタは「default._domainkey」となっており、ホスト名で分けるということはできないようです。
ざっと調べてもうまい方法が見つけられず、困っています。
かなり特殊な事例だと思うのですが、何かアイディアをいただけると幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 登録するのはホスト名ではなく公開鍵です。

Comment: すみません、「default._domainkey」の部分はセレクタというんですね。先ほど質問文は修正しておきました。